# Передать текущее значение выбранного select в onclick

Tags: javascript

Как передать текущее значение выбранного select в onclick ?
Например из селекта

```
<select name="option[227]">
        <option value="">Выберите Опцию</option>
         <option value="19">Опция 3 </option>
         <option value="18">Опция 2 </option>
         <option value="17">Опция 1 </option>
 </select>
```

В `<a href="#" onclick="add('Значение select');">+</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прямо на "голом" `JS` + `onclick`, то как то так:

```js
function add(selectEl){
    var value = (selectEl) ? selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value : null;
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select id="test">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick="add(document.querySelector('#test'))">Test</a>
```

При этом в функцию передается не значение, а сам элемент списка, иначе громоздко писать прямо в атрибуте `onclick`.

Но лучше использовать события + [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Answer (score 2):

Пример с сайта jQuery

```html
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

```js
function add() {
    var a = $( "#myselect" ).val();
    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();